# Put method throws 500 error ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-put

I'm using something like REST API on my web site. And I'm using PUT method.

```
[HttpPut]
 public ActionResult OrderChapter(ClientOrder order)
```

But it's not Web API, it's MVC controller. At first I was receiving 405 error (Method Not Allowed). Google said that I need to remove the WebDAVModule

```
<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

After this I have a 500 error. And it's not my code. Adding this changed nothing:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

My hoster says that PUT, PATCH and DELETE methods are not explicitly prohibited.

What's wrong? Maybe in settings of IIS this methods are not allowed?

Comment: Does everything work for post? There could be a problem with put. For example angularjs doesn't allow body for put. Only parameters, so action might not be properly resolved.

Comment: Yes, it's working for post. I'm using jQuery.ajax. So, seems that I should use post instead of put?

Comment: Use Fiddler and check wheter PUT request contains payload in body. If is is not you can either switch to POST or use query string parameters instead od the body.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, error code `#500` has to do with some internal server error and it's also its official definition.

In layman's terms, that seems that there is something wrong with your code in the `PUT` action, a quick debugging of your `PUT` action method will give you the answer to the problem, probably some exception is been thrown and that is translated to 500 Error code by your web-server (e.g IIS).

Comment: All my code is fine, it's working on my IIS Express, but doesn't works on the web hosting. I commented all parts of code which could throw an exception.